# android studio app keeps stopping when run on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have 2 activities, the main activity has a button that is supposed to send the user to the other activity when clicked on

```
package com.example.messingaround;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button seeList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        seeList = (Button)findViewById(R.id.seeList);
        seeList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

But whenever I try to run the app, it says app keeps stopping
[enter image description here][1]

In my logcat this keeps repeating

```
2022-02-24 19:11:26.985 1798-28412/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-02-24 19:11:26.985 1798-28412/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-02-24 19:11:27.989 1798-28412/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-02-24 19:11:27.989 1798-28412/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-02-24 19:11:28.994 1798-28412/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-02-24 19:11:28.994 1798-28412/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-02-24 19:11:29.994 1798-28412/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
```

Comment: You're crashing.  There should be a stack trace in your log.  The lines you pasted are irrelevant.

Comment: This is just the virtual GPS sensor; likely you might be missing GL drivers.